# MSVS/MSVC function alias

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

Попытки повторить аналог поведения `__attribute__ ((alias ("realfunc")))` из GCC в MSVS/MSVC успехом не закончились. Что не так? и есть ли решения на базе `pragma`, `macro`?

Вот тест на котором была попытка заставить работать:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "main.h"

#pragma comment( user, "Compiled on " __DATE__ " at " __TIME__ )

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        printf("%d) [%d]\n", i, test_virtual(i));

    (void) getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

main.h

```
//__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl test_virtual(int);
//__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl test_virtual(int);
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl test_realy(int);
int test_virtual(int);
```

fun.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "main.h"

__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl test_realy(int a)
{
    return a + 10;
}

#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:test_virtual=test_realy")
```

Пробовал все возможные на мой взгляд варианты с декорациями имен функций (`__stdcall`,`__cdecl`), толку нет.

Comment: Поясните по-человечески чего вы хотите получить, тут не все гуру одновременно и GCC и MSVC

Comment: Мне кажется, что без def файла тут не обойтись. Но вообще не очень понятно, зачем так заморачиваться, может реализовать эту функцию вызовом основной функции?

Comment: Куда уж человечнее :) Перефразирую по другому: как делать алиас на функцию в MSVS/MSVC ?

Comment: @VTT, можно конечно, но это только пример, в реальности все сложнее и его больше. А так да, самый способ в лоб из функции звать другую функцию, и содержать весь этот зоопарк из за mangle names..

Comment: А при чем тут mangled names?

Comment: в результате именно это требуеться, если по сути. Надо алиасы прописать со ссылками на другие функции, что и должна делать `pragma comment(linker,EXPORT..`

Comment: Так а при чем тут mangled names? алиасы - это не mangled names (которых в С вообще нет). Совершенно непонятно, чем вас не устраивает способ с обычной реализацией функции - городить огород из компиляторно-специфичных конструкций как-то сомнительно. У менять возникает ощущение, что тут имеет место проблема XY.

Comment: Таблица символов, думаю об одном, пишу о другом :) про проблему, вероятно, вам виднее @VTT, вот забавно что по делу, мало кто что выразил, а если описался, так тут пожалуйста :) с def файлом тоже не работает кстати.

Comment: @VTT, про mangled names, они есть в С, с учётом использования предикатов `_cdecl`,`_stdcall`,`_fastcall` :) если нет сказать чего по сути, то иногда лучше молчать

Comment: `_cdecl`, `_stdcall`, `_fastcall` - не предикаты, а компиляторно-специфичные соглашения о вызовах. А механизмы name mangling для С не требуются, так как язык не предусматривает возможности перегружать или как-то различать функции иначе как по идентификатору.

Comment: Посмотрите как `test_realy` экспортируется системой и используйте это имя. Будет что-то типа такого: `#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:test_virtual=_test_realy")`

Comment: Да, да, именно так. Но: `main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _test_virtual в функции _main`, текущая строка: `#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:_test_virtual=_test_realy")`. Как бы увидеть как линкер в конечном итоге эту прагму воспринимает..

Comment: И забавно то что он прагму точно видит, и она его не смущает, если поправить таргет в прагме, то ругаеться : `error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_testrealy"`, тут что то с 'областью видимости', если так можно назвать.. Где ее правильнее объявлять то? где используется, где сам таргет, или везде (в хеадере) ? в gcc например, строго в области видимости таргет функции.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Вы компилируете DLL? Или DLL тут вообще ни при чем?

Comment: Нет, длл тут вообще не причём, @Ant

Comment: Тогда вернёмся к первому комментарию - что вы делаете.

Comment: Если вам "мешает" чужой код, его можно уничтожить, например если мешает alias("ljrwlj")  то удалить его можно переопределением `#define alias(a)` (присваиваем пусто). Ещё можно удалить автозаменой. А если вам нужно определённое поведение - то поясните что нужно.

Comment: Третий комментарий сверху,  если и там непонятно, то проще не вникать :)